# Package `tcolorbox` within `titlesec`

Tags: chapters, titlesec, tcolorbox

It may not be a very good idea, but I am trying to use `tcolorbox`  for formatting `titlesec`  as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\chaptauthor}{}
\newcommand{\chaptrans}{}

\tcbset{
    enhanced,
    colback=red!5!white,
    boxrule=0.1pt,
    colframe=red!75!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries
}

\titleformat{\chapter}% command to format the chapter titles
[display]% shape/type of title
{}% formatting commands applied to both label and title
{\flushright \normalsize \color[rgb]{0.5,0,0.1} \MakeUppercase  \chaptertitlename  \hspace{1 ex}  {\fontsize{60}{60} \selectfont \color[rgb]{0.5,0,0.1} \sffamily  \thechapter} }
{0em}% separation between number and chapter title; we've already covered this with the box
{\LARGE\bfseries}% additional formatting command for title itself not applied to number
[% everything inside [...] below comes after the title
\hfill% 
\normalsize\normalfont% reset font formatting
%\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}% add a half-space of vertical space before author
%\hspace*{0.5in}% indent author name width of chapter number box 
{\begin{tcolorbox}[width=5cm]%
\begin{tabular}{rl}%
Author: & \kern-0.5em\chaptauthor \\
Translator: & \kern-0.5em\chaptrans\\
\end{tabular}%
\end{tcolorbox}%
}]% end of what comes after title


%\titlespacing*{\chapter}% spacing commands for chapter titles; the star unindents first line afterwards
%     {0em}% spacing to left of chapter title
%     {0ex}% vertical space before title 
%     {3\baselineskip}% vertical spacing after title; here set to 3 lines 


\begin{document}
\title{A title}
\maketitle

\frontmatter
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\renewcommand{\chaptauthor}{Author}
\renewcommand{\chaptrans}{Translator}
\chapter{One chapter}
\lipsum[5-9]
\chapter{Another chapter}
\lipsum[4-7]
\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image]

How should I change the code to put the box directly below `Chapter 1`, that is, make it occupy the position occupied by the Author and Translator without `tcolorbox` (you may remove `tcolorbox`  to see this)?

=========================Edit============================

This is where I would like it to be, in case it is not clear:

[image]

Comment: You know that the box appears in the `ToC` as well? And your question is a little bit unclear. Shall the white space above and below the `tcolorbox` be removed

Comment: Yes, I know how to remove that! :-)

Comment: `@Christian Hupfer`, yes, and every other bad element should also be removed.

Comment: Every bad element  :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tcolorbox` boxes have vertical spacings above and below the box. This can be switched off using `nobeforeafter` option.

The additional space after the box is due to `\titleformat` etc. Use `\titlespacing` to set the vertical spacing after the chapter title to, say, `\baselineskip`  -- this is the last parameter of `\titlespacing`.

I additionally wrapped a command around the box to make additions/changes easier to maintain.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\chaptauthor}{}
\newcommand{\chaptrans}{}

\tcbset{
    enhanced,
    colback=red!5!white,
    boxrule=0.1pt,
    colframe=red!75!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries
}

\newtcolorbox{myauthorbox}[1][]{%
    enhanced,
    colback=red!5!white,
    boxrule=0.1pt,
    colframe=red!75!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    nobeforeafter,
    #1
}%

\newcommand{\authorbox}[3][width=5cm]{%
\begin{myauthorbox}[#1]
    \begin{tabular}{rl}
      Author:     & \kern-0.5em #2 \\
      Translator: & \kern-0.5em #3 \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{myauthorbox}%
}


\titleformat{\chapter}% command to format the chapter titles
[display]% shape/type of title
{}% formatting commands applied to both label and title
{\flushright \normalsize \color[rgb]{0.5,0,0.1} \MakeUppercase  \chaptertitlename  \hspace{1 ex}  {\fontsize{60}{60} \selectfont \color[rgb]{0.5,0,0.1} \sffamily  \thechapter} }
{0em}% separation between number and chapter title; we've already covered this with the box
{\LARGE\bfseries}% additional formatting command for title itself not applied to number
[% everything inside [...] below comes after the title
\hfill%  For right alignment of the box
\normalsize\normalfont% reset font formatting
%\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}% add a half-space of vertical space before author
%\hspace*{0.5in}% indent author name width of chapter number box 
{%
  \authorbox[width=5cm]{\chaptauthor}{\chaptrans}%
}]% end of what comes after title


\titlespacing*{\chapter}% spacing commands for chapter titles; the star unindents first line afterwards
     {0em}% spacing to left of chapter title
     {0ex}% vertical space before title 
     {1\baselineskip}% vertical spacing after title; here set to 3 lines 


\begin{document}
\title{A title}
\maketitle

\frontmatter
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\renewcommand{\chaptauthor}{Author}
\renewcommand{\chaptrans}{Translator}
\chapter{One chapter}
\lipsum[5-9]
\chapter{Another chapter}
\lipsum[4-7]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not exactly what I want. In fact, I want the box to be exactly below the text "Chapter 1" not below "One chapter"! As mentioned in the question, remove the `tcolorbox` and you will see where I want it to be.

Comment: @usr203050: I'll change

Comment: @usr203050: Updated

Comment: `@Christian Hupfer`, accepted. :-)

Comment: @usr203050: Actually, I 'hate' titlesec ;-) But thanks

Comment: I like it, is there a better choice in your opinion? Which does everything `titlesec` can do? In a simpler manner?

Comment: @usr203050: I've no idea...