# It is possible to use tcolorbox with titlecontents

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, tcolorbox

Deer,
I tried to make a framed section into my table of content

```
\titlecontents{section}[3.5cm]
{\addvspace{1em}}
{}
{}
{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=AntiqueWhite, colback=AntiqueWhite]
        \contentslabel{0.5cm}\normalcolor\hfill\contentspage
    \end{tcolorbox}}
```

but that di not not print contentlabel.
I would like to know if they are a way to do it?

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how titlesec does it, but you could try modifying \l@section directly.

Comment: Here's one of my rare `titlesec` answers, with a tcolorbox:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258559/package-tcolorbox-within-titlesec

Comment: I just noted that you used the `memoir` tag? Are you really screwing up `memoir`'s excellent features with something like `titlesec`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `\titlecontents` according to its definition. The fourth argument is the one for typesetting the toc entry of numbered sections, not the sixth argument. Moreover, the section title (enclosed in braces) is appended to the code of this argument, so this should be a command taking an argument if you want to put the title into a box.

You need something like this:

```
\newcommand\boxed[1]%
  {\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=AntiqueWhite, colback=AntiqueWhite]
   \contentslabel{0.5cm}#1\hfill\contentspage
   \end{tcolorbox}%
  }
\titlecontents{section}[0cm]%
  {\addvspace{1em}}%
  {\boxed}%
  {}%
  {}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newcommand\boxed[1]%
  {\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=AntiqueWhite, colback=AntiqueWhite]%
   \contentslabel{0.5cm}#1\hfill\contentspage
   \end{tcolorbox}%
  }
\titlecontents{section}[0cm]%
  {\addvspace{1em}}%
  {\boxed}%
  {}%
  {}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Some section title}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```